# Python 2.7 and OpenCV different result using 64bit and 32bit, possible bug?

Tags: python, debugging, opencv, geometry

i am testing the following code using two windows OS one on 64bit and one 32bit. Both machine have installed Python 2.7 and the openCV from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

```
opencv-python-2.4.3.win32-py2.7.‌exe = 32 bit 
opencv-python-2.4.3.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe = 64 bit
```

in **64bit** the result fitting an ellipse is

```
(center, size, angle)
((560030.1875, 6362089.0), (21.186540603637695, 56.54529571533203), 176.27346801757812)
```

in **32bit** the result fitting an ellipse is

```
(center, size, angle)
((560030.625, 6362066.5), (10.480490684509277, 17.20206642150879), 144.34889221191406)
```

the code i used for the test is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv

points = [(560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258),
 (560036.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
 (560036.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
 (560036.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
 (560037.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
 (560037.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
 (560036.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
 (560036.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
 (560035.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
 (560035.4495758876, 6362062.390493258),
 (560034.9495758876, 6362062.390493258),
 (560034.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
 (560032.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
 (560032.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
 (560030.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
 (560030.4495758876, 6362061.390493258),
 (560029.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
 (560029.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
 (560029.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
 (560029.4495758876, 6362059.890493258),
 (560028.9495758876, 6362059.890493258),
 (560028.9495758876, 6362059.390493258),
 (560028.4495758876, 6362059.390493258),
 (560028.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
 (560027.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
 (560027.4495758876, 6362058.390493258),
 (560026.9495758876, 6362058.390493258),
 (560026.9495758876, 6362057.890493258),
 (560025.4495758876, 6362057.890493258),
 (560025.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
 (560023.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
 (560023.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
 (560023.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
 (560023.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
 (560024.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
 (560024.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
 (560024.9495758876, 6362063.390493258),
 (560024.9495758876, 6362064.390493258),
 (560025.4495758876, 6362064.390493258),
 (560025.4495758876, 6362065.390493258),
 (560025.9495758876, 6362065.390493258),
 (560025.9495758876, 6362065.890493258),
 (560026.4495758876, 6362065.890493258),
 (560026.4495758876, 6362066.890493258),
 (560026.9495758876, 6362066.890493258),
 (560026.9495758876, 6362068.390493258),
 (560027.4495758876, 6362068.390493258),
 (560027.4495758876, 6362068.890493258),
 (560027.9495758876, 6362068.890493258),
 (560027.9495758876, 6362069.390493258),
 (560028.4495758876, 6362069.390493258),
 (560028.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
 (560033.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
 (560033.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
 (560033.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
 (560033.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
 (560034.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
 (560034.4495758876, 6362071.390493258),
 (560034.9495758876, 6362071.390493258),
 (560034.9495758876, 6362071.890493258),
 (560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258)]

x = np.array(points)[:,0]
y = np.array(points)[:,1]

PointArray2D32f = cv.CreateMat(1, len(points), cv.CV_32FC2)
for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(points):
    PointArray2D32f[0, i] = (x, y)
    # Fits ellipse to current contour.
    (center, size, angle) = cv.FitEllipse2(PointArray2D32f)

print (center, size, angle)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fitting ellipses is normally done by a randomized process, since there are so many degrees of freedom.  It is likely that you are seeing different results because the algorithm is simply not deterministic.

The algorithm used by OpenCV to fit an ellipse is the [Randomized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_Hough_transform).

Comment: Dear Chris. about "randomized process" if i run several times on 32bit or 64bit i got always the some values.

Comment: It could be the random seed used by the algorithm

Comment: thanks for your link on Wiki. but why if i run the points value on my machine (64bit) i got always (21.186540603637695, 56.54529571533203) and if i run on 32bit i got always (10.480490684509277, 17.20206642150879)?

Comment: it's hard to understand the extact result. Please, Do you know a way to fit an ellispe in python in order to see which result is the most real?

Comment: My guess is that it's due to OpenCV's method of doing random number generation.  They use the cv.RNG module for generating random numbers, which takes a 64 bit seed.  Perhaps this is impacting your results.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for in your second question.  If you think one is an outlier, you can generate multiple ellipses with a subset of your points and make a decision from multiple outputs.  Alternatively, you could fit an ellipse with [RANSAC](http://se.cs.ait.ac.th/cvwiki/opencv:tutorial:fitting_ellipse_using_ransac_algorithm)

Comment: i need to find a benckmark algorithm in order to test the data. Do you know some solution, please?

Comment: A benchmark would be hand-drawn ellipses through the points.  If you had a better algorithm, you probably wouldn't use this one, as OpenCV's fit ellipse is one of the faster implementations.  In any case, that sounds like a totally separate question.  Hope this helped.

Comment: Sorry if i disturb you again with this question. Do you know the algorithm used by OpenCV to compute smallest circle enclosing an input feature (cv.MinEnclosingCircle)?

Comment: @Gianni Sorry, I'm not familiar with that function.  The great thing about OpenCV is that it's open source, so if you're very interested you can go look at the source to see what the algorithm is doing.